# Where can I find Spanish & Portuguese versions of the System Usability Scale (SUS)?

Tags: usability, sus

I've found mention of them BUT, I don't find them.  Ideally, I seek the all-positive versions. Thanks!

Comment: At the other end of a Google search, I think.

Comment: If you can find a published study which used one of them, write directly to the corresponding author and ask for it. They may just give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

André is right. I found a Portuguese one for you: http://meiert.com/en/blog/20091127/sus-how-to-grade/ (near the bottom of post, in updates).

There's also a good chance that you are seeing references to versions of the SUS that the researchers themselves have translated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but just in case someone else needs it for future reference, try [Sistema de Escalas de Usabilidad: ¿qué es y para qué sirve?](http://uxpanol.com/teoria/sistema-de-escalas-de-usabilidad-que-es-y-para-que-sirve/) in Spanish

*(Disclaimer: I'm the author of the article)*